# How do I accept bitbucket transfer?

Tags: bitbucket, transfer

I have transfered ownership of a bitbucket repo from a user to another user.
But I can't accept the transfer... I've read the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/change-or-transfer-repository-ownership-289964397.html) but I don't have the transfer request message...

I just have this : [image]

How can I accept this transfer ?

Comment: Did you accidentally try to transfer from a user to a team? I hit the problem with this use case. The team didn't have any project and I couldn't click the Accept button. Solved it by creating a project in the team, revoking the transfer and restarting the transfer process.